# Is there a way to compile and bundle another html file in tauri?

Tags: reactjs, rust, tauri

I am using tauri (1.2.5) with reactjs and I'm creating a splashscreen for my app. I've done this by creating a splashscreen.html file in the root directory (same dir as index.html) with this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Elect</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/splashscreen.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In splashscreen.tsx is the splashscreen design and reference to a splashscreen.scss for animation. The splashscreen window is refered to in the tauri.conf.json file like this:

```
{
    "width": 400,
    "height": 200,
    "decorations": false,
    "url": "splashscreen.html",
    "label": "splashscreen",
    "center": true,
    "transparent": true,
    "skipTaskbar": true,
    "alwaysOnTop": true,
    "title": "Elect"
}
```

Everything works when using dev mode (`yarn tauri dev`), but when I build the app, the splashscreen.html file is not included or compiled so is not found by the app when run (it seems to default to rendering index.html). I can't just copy the file into the dist dir as it includes a sass file.

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Fair enough, but if the Rust code isn't the problem you don't need the Rust tag, and if it *might* be the problem you should probably post the relevant bits

Comment: Yes it is a possibilty that the solution involves rust code as there are rust build scripts (auto generated by tauri) that compile the project.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the `splashscreen.html` file is not included in the dist could be that it's not being recognized as an entry point by the build system. You have to add an entry point for `splashscreen.html` in `module.exports` of your `webpack.config.js` file, which is used by Tauri to build your app:

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.tsx', // your main entry
    splashscreen: './splashscreen.html' // add this entry point
  },
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was editing `vite.config.ts` like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig(async () => ({
  ...
  build: {
    ...
    rollupOptions: {
        input: {
            index: "./index.html",
            splashscreen: "./splashscreen.html",
        },
    },
  },
}));
```